# Symfony 4/javascript - UniqueEntity constraint on relation

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony4

I'm working on Symfony 4.2 form for the Admin registration. My Admin entity has a One to One bidirectional relation to a City entity. I wanted to provide the user with an error message for when the City he provided is already bound to an existing Admin. Firstly I tried using the same method I use to prevent duplicate emails in other entities. I put a UniqueEntity constraint in both entities and a space for forms errors in my template.

Admin.php

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AdminRepository")
 *  * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"city"},
 *     message="error message here"
 * )
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Admin
{ ... }
```

City.php

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="city")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"admin"},
 *     message="error message here"
 * )
 */
class City
{...}
```

(I suppose annotations syntax is different because the Admin table was created a few months ago, while I was still on Symfony 4.0)

But I must be missing something, or it works different with relations, because I still get the SQL error message page "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_3946A254A73F0036'".

I also thought of a javascript method to call for the database and check whether the City being provided by the user is already associated to an Admin, which would be even better because no refresh and all, but I can't retrieve results from my request.

client-side, called on keyup

```
function cityRequest(){
    var cityCode = document.getElementById("city").value;
    if(cityCode) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "{{ path('checkCity')}}",
            data: {
            city_code:cityCode,
        },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#cityMsg').html(response);
            }
        });
    } else { 
        ...
    }
}
```

The request controller

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class AjaxController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/ajaxrequest", name="checkCity", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function checkCity(Request $request)
    {
        $code= $request->get('city_code');
        $response = new JsonResponse(array(
            'message' => $code));
        return $response;
    }
}
```

In the response, 'message' displays null but I want it to be the string entered by the user (then I could proceed to fetch my city and check for an existing admin...)

As I am at a stall with both methods, your help is greatly appreciated.. Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using the validator ? https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: I believe that's what I'm doing when I use the UniqueEntity Constraint ? I don't see any other constraint that would fit

Answer (score 2):

So you have two ways of doing that

The first one:

```
//City.php
/**
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *      fields={"admin"},
        repositoryMethod = "findAdmin"),
 *      message="error message here"
 * )
*/
class City
{...}





//CityRepository.php
public function findAdmin($admin)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')->leftJoin('c.admin', 'a')
            ->andWhere('a = :admin')
            ->setParameter('admin', $admin)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }


//YourController.php
if($formAdmin->isSubmitted()) 
{
    $repoAdmin = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Admin::class); 
    $repoCity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(City::class);  
    $city->setAdmin($admin);
    if($formAdmin->isValid()){      
        $admin->setCity($city) 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
        $em->persist($admin); 
        $em->persist($city);`enter code here`
        $em->flush(); 
    }
}
```

The second one:

```
//YourController.php
if($formAdmin->isSubmitted()) 
{
    $repoAdmin = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Admin::class); 
    $repoCity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(City::class);  
    $city->setAdmin($admin);
    if($formAdmin->isValid() && $admin->getCity()==null){       //you just add this controller, it is a controller check level
        $admin->setCity($city) 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
        $em->persist($admin); 
        $em->persist($city);
        $em->flush(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what my form handling looks like ` if($formAdmin->isSubmitted() && $formAdmin->isValid())
    {
        $repoAdmin = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Admin::class);
        $repoCity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(City::class);
            
        $admin->setCity($city)
        $city->setAdmin($admin);
            
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($admin);
        $em->persist($city);
            
        $em->flush();
    }`

Comment: you should add the two line that i mentioned before the ' if($formAdmin->isSubmitted() && $formAdmin->isValid())'

Comment: which means :
$city->setAdmin($admin);
$admin->setCity($city);
then
 ' if($formAdmin->isSubmitted() && $formAdmin->isValid())'

Comment: $city is only supposed to exist after the form is submitted. I tried your suggestion with a blank City object and still getting the same error

Comment: which entity is the owning side

Comment: The city property in the Admin entity is the owning side

Comment: feel free to modify the findAdmin() method to suit your case because i don't how did you rename your attributs